# Filter RESTEasy json translation - I don't want to send every field!

Tags: json, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy to send objects over my rest api with JSON.  It's very convenient - every field is automatically populated in the JSON object.  But there are some fields (e.g. `passwordhash`) that I'd rather not send.  I'd also like to strip out any null values - there's no need to send those.

Can I affect how JSON is created?

I'm using Jettison, RESTEasy 2.0.1.GA and, *I think*, JAXB, although I'm having an infuriatingly-hard time actually being sure of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what are you using to work with JSON. If you are using JAXB and Jettison, you can use @XmlTransient to avoid sending the annotated fields. If you are using Jackson you can use @JsonIgnore. No matter which option are you using NULL values should be omitted by default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to those annotations.  null values are definitely not being omitted, though, and sometimes my objects are like 90% null fields!

Comment: Hmmm.. it's weird. Which configuration are you using Jettison + JAXB, Jackson + JAXB or just Jackson? Which resteasy version are you using?

Comment: You know... I don't know.  I just started using resteasy 2.0.1 and don't know the specifics.  I am using the default configuration, I guess.

Comment: I've figured out, I think, that I'm not using Jackson, and @XmlTransient seems to have no effect (I annotated the relevant getter function). I'm stuck!

Comment: So I *was* using Jackson, but didn't have every jar I needed, I guess. @JsonIgnore worked a charm.

Comment: If you want to skip null values mapping see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null