# Jackson not ignoring null values

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, jax-rs

Here is my object

```
public class TokenTO {
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String authCode;
    private String authToken;
    ....
}
```

and when I get the `JSON` response I see

```
{"clientId":null,"clientSecret":null,"authCode":null,"authToken":"312301658396979836978200915715157679015:80bf41c2-bc97-492f-a65e-172bef9efb7c:922000000"}
```

My `JacksonContextResolver` looks like

```
public JacksonContextResolver() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS);

        final AnnotationIntrospector annotationIntrospector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        objectMapper
                .enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
                .setDeserializationConfig(objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(annotationIntrospector))
                .setSerializationConfig(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(annotationIntrospector));
    }
```

I tried answers in  [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null) and [jackson ignore empty values (or null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-ignore-empty-values-or-null) but none of them work.

My `maven` dependencies look like

```
 <properties>
     <jaxrs-api.version>3.0.8.Final</jaxrs-api.version>
     <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
     <resteasy-jaxrs.version>3.0.9.Final</resteasy-jaxrs.version>
     <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <jaxrs-api.version>3.0.8.Final</jaxrs-api.version>
 </properties>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Question**

How do I get rid of `null` values in `JSON`?

Comment: `org.codehaus.jackson`? In 2014?

Comment: better recommendations please @fge

Comment: Do you have to use that old version of Jackson? Last release of Jackson 1 was 1 1/2 years ago. ... I haven't used it for 2 years. Maybe it's an old bug.

Comment: Why do you have `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS`?

Comment: Well, it's been years since Jackson 2.x is out; the most recent version is 2.4.x, you should really go with that

Comment: @daydreamer: new version: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I removed `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS` but I still get `null`s. I am going to try newer `Jackson` version

Answer (score 1):

Since I am using `Java EE 7`, I tried to make use of [JSON Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm).

The changes I made is

for testing, I added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and in source code, I created `JSON` as

```
public JsonObject getAuthToken(@Nonnull final TokenManager tokenManager) {
        final String token = tokenManager.getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, authCode);
        return Json.createObjectBuilder().add("authToken", token).build();
    }
```

and for Testing, I did something as

```
final JsonObject jsonReply = getJsonObjectFromResponse(response);
assertNotNull(jsonReply.getString("authToken"));
```

and

```
    @Nonnull
    protected JsonObject getJsonObjectFromResponse(@Nonnull final Response response) {
        final JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.readEntity(String.class)));
        return jsonReader.readObject();
    }
```

Now, when deployed, I only see what I create

```
{"authToken":"165099393037221788471723459805657963846:8b0f2514-938f-4509-964f-ee073dbab4ed:238000000"}
```

So I am **not** using `Jackson` at all and my code is lot more cleaner