# Object to Json including only fields not null

Tags: java, string, json

I have an object named Item with plenty of fields. I'm using a Java JSON (json-io) library to serialize its state in a File:

```
String json = JsonWriter.objectToJson(item);
// Write String to File
```

I'd like to make the json String less verbose so that it does not include null values (if possible also boolean which are false). Is it possible to do it somehow ? 
Thanks

Comment: don't forget to add the name of programming language tags to your questions. this will bring right people to your questions

Comment: if there is an answer to compare with null and order you need to search the methode toJson to add configuration example for compare that i use  assertJsonEquals("{\"test\":[1,2,3]}", "{\"test\":[3,2,1]}",Configuration.empty().when(Option.IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER).when(Option.TREATING_NULL_AS_ABSENT) );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend using jackson mapper if possible. 
Check out these two questions:

[Jackson serialization: ignore empty values (or null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-ignore-empty-values-or-null)

[How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Comment: Thanks, seems the best option for me.