# How to tell Jackson to ignore empty object during deserialization?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

At the deserialization process (which as I understand is the process of converting JSON data into a Java Object), how can I tell Jackson that when it reads a object that contains no data, it should be ignored?

I'm using Jackson 2.6.6 and Spring 4.2.6

The JSON data received by my controller is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "description": "A description",
    "containedObject": {}
}
```

The problem is that the object "containedObject" is interpreted as is and it's being instantiated. Therefore, as soon as my controller reads this JSON data, it produces an instance of the ContainedObject object type but I need this to be null instead.

The easiest and fastest solution would be that in the JSON data received, this value be null like this:

```
 {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "A description",
        "containedObject": null
    }
```

But this isn't possible since I'm not in control of the JSON data that is sent to me.

Is there an annotation ([like this explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null)) that works for the deserialization process and could be helpfull in my situation?

I leave a representation of my classes for more information:

My entity class is as follows:

```
public class Entity {
    private long id;
    private String description;
    private ContainedObject containedObject;

//Contructor, getters and setters omitted

}
```

And my contained object class as follows:

```
public class ContainedObject {
    private long contObjId;
    private String aString;

//Contructor, getters and setters omitted

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use a `JsonDeserializer`. Inspect the field in question, determine, if it is `emtpy` and return `null`, so your `ContainedObject` would be null.

Something like this (semi-pseudo):

```
 public class MyDes extends JsonDeserializer<ContainedObject> {

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            //read the JsonNode and determine if it is empty JSON object
            //and if so return null

            if (node is empty....) {
                return null;
            }
            return node;
        }

    }
```

then in your model:

```
 public class Entity {
    private long id;
    private String description;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyDes.class)
    private ContainedObject containedObject;

   //Contructor, getters and setters omitted

 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would be my solution if I still don't find an annotation that do the job. Thank you!

Comment: This is a solution that i have used widely. As far as i know, no annotation would do what you would achieve with this Deserializer.

Comment: @MauricioCampagner Don't forget to accept the answer that has been most useful to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a custom deserializer as follows:

```
public class Entity {
    private long id;
    private String description;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyToNullObject.class)
    private ContainedObject containedObject;

//Contructor, getters and setters omitted

}


public class EmptyToNullObject extends JsonDeserializer<ContainedObject> {

  public ContainedObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    long contObjId = (Long) ((LongNode) node.get("contObjId")).numberValue();
    String aString = node.get("aString").asText();
    if(aString.equals("") && contObjId == 0L) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return new ContainedObject(contObjId, aString);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I think it's because the field is known, but it's empty, so Jackson doesn't ignore it. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think this answer and Mechkovs are equivalent. I have used both, I now have a preference for @JsonDeserialize because it doesn't require extending the JsonDeserializer.

Comment: I have realised him answer after I edited. He answered early. You should accept him answer

Comment: How to make it common for any type and not just for ContainedObject?

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 : This is mostly used. @JsonInclude is used to exclude properties with empty/null/default values.Use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) or @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) as per your requirement.

```
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class Employee {

        private String empId;
        private String firstName;

        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        private String lastName;
        private String address;
        private String emailId;

   }
```

More info about the jackson annotations :  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Approach 2 : GSON

use GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: @JsonInclude doesn't work. According to the documentation this annotation is for the serialization process only

The approach 2 is helpfull, but I want to know if there's a way to do that with a Jackson's annotation