# Jackson JSON serialization: How to ignore a nested object when all its fields are null?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson and I have some JSON schema objects set up something like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Person {

    String name;
    Child child = new Child();
    Sibling sibling = new Sibling();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }
    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    public Sibling getSibling() {
        return sibling;
    }
    public void setSibling(Sibling sibling) {
        this.sibling = sibling;
    }
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Child {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Sibling {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to ignore all fields that are null or empty, which works fine. But I also want to ignore objects with fields that are all null or empty. For example:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John Doe");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
```

The resulting JSON string is `{"name":"John Doe","child":{},"sibling":{}}`, but I want it to be `{"name":"John Doe"}`. `Child` and `Sibling` need to be initialized when `Person` is created so I don't want to change that. Is there a way to make Jackson treat objects with null fields as null with a custom serializer? I've seen examples of using custom serializers for specific types of objects but I need one that would work for any object.

Comment: You have to write a custom deserializer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366524/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-empty-object-during-deserialization

Comment: I'm looking for solution for serialization, not deserialization, as well as one that works with all object types.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in an arguably simpler way without custom serialiser(s) for `Person` or `Child` and `Sibling` but with `CUSTOM` include and passing the type of the field as filter.

First of all define correct `equals` methods for `Child` and `Sibling`. Then, to filter nested objects that are equal to what their default constructor would return, annotate the pertinent getters in `Person` like this:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Child.class)
public Child getChild() {
    return child;
}

@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Sibling.class)
public Sibling getSibling() {
    return sibling;
}
```

Setting `valueFilter` to `Child.class` above has the effect of creating an object with the default constructor `Child emptyChild = new Child()` and then to decide that another object `Child child` should be serialised checks that `emptyChild.equals(child)` is false

[docs for valueFilter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html#valueFilter())

Comment: This works but what about if you don't initialize Child or Sibling inside Person? It would return null for both of them even though Person has NOT_EMPTY specified in its definition

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think ignoring null values on the serializer level should be enough:

```java
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```