# Jackson hide empty objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

How i can hide empty {} objects after serialize?
I have object with null values, after *objectMapper.writeValueAsString* i get JSON like :

```
{
"stringValue": "1",
"objectValue": {}
}
```

How can i exclude empty (`field2`) fileds from `json`? 
I can't set null to every object becouse i `serialize` many classes

P.S.i already setup

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: Can you please try  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) annotation on fields which you want to exclude.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366524/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-empty-object-during-deserialization the reversed issue but I think custom serializer can work as well

Comment: @RaheelaAslam thx, but this don't work with empty object. I try use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  on filed, but this filed is not null

Comment: @Akceptor thx, but this is using in library, I can`t write custom serializer for each domain class

Comment: @IgorFedorov then did you tried NON_EMPTY annotation on field ?

Comment: @RaheelaAslam yea, i tried this. Only custom serializer can exclude empty objects from result json, but it doesn't suit me. Thanks