# Treatment for sending a supposedly empty json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend

how do I handle a submission of a supposedly empty JSON, this way ==> {} ? I can't catch this error. It does not appear as null or as empty.

I have been getting this error message: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type"" nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException"

This JASON goes to a "List"

Comment: If you're expecting a list, the empty JSON should be `[]`.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Possibly related: [How to tell Jackson to ignore empty object during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40366524/12567365).