# Ignore Empty Collections during Serialisation

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have read questions like these [@JsonInclude to ignore null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null).
This works for me for regular fields within an entity  but not for Collections. In case of empty Collections within an entity, Json serialisation gives a null value.

How does one do a equivalent ignore for collections ?

Comment: What's the point of having null values in your collection in the first place?

Comment: do you mean like if an entity has a List and this list has a null object ?

Comment: or you mean an empty collection?

Comment: I mean empty collections. The collection is not yet initialised and will be initialised at a later point of time with data. Editing the question to make it clear.

Comment: null is different from empty list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with the annotation

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
private Collection field;
```

Comment: It works - in my version it is @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY). My bad, I was thinking of them as null collection rather than an empty collection.

Answer (score 2):

Since the **Jackson 2.x** it provides `@JsonInclude` annotation that controls serialization of a class as a whole or its individual fields based on their values during serialization. It recognizes following annotations as:

**`Include.NON_NULL`**  Indicates that only non-null properties should be serialized.

**`Include.NON_EMPTY`** Indicates that only non-null and non-empty properties should be serialized. This is actually the superset of `Include.NON_NULL`

Hence over a collection `Include.NON_EMPTY` will work like

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
private Collection field;
```

or you can put it over the class to impact upon the whole model like

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Foo {
}
```