# I want to remove null and "" values data from JSON responce output

Tags: java, json

here I am using Annotation on Entity class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class MappingDTO {

    private String mid; 
    private String location;
    private String department;
    private String role;
    private String tenent_id;
    private String cid;
    private ArrayList<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOAL;
    //setters and getters
}
```

and using Jar is

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.6.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

My Current output

```
{
"mid":"1",
"location":"",
"department":"IT"
"role":"Developer",
"tenent_id":"",
"cid":"1001",
"categoryDTOAL":null
}
```

Expected Output

```
 {
"mid":"1",
"department":"IT"
"role":"Developer",
"cid":"1001",
}
```

> How to i'm solve it when my this Annotation is failed to solve this
>   problem

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089705/2310289

Comment: Finally I m getting Answer  
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency> ` add this jar and Use Annotation `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)`  Here i am importing  `import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ignore null or "" value then you can tru `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`  or `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` begore class.

you can find below sample code:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) 
public static class Test {

}
```

you can also use `@JsonIgnore` on any fix column as per your use case.

Comment: so what is wrong with the OP's code?

Comment: Hello @Mayank Sharma its not working on my case....

Comment: then try to use  `@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)`
intead of `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` or try to use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: @mayank Sharma when i am using '@JsonIgnore' in my "mid" its forcefully remove it . i want to remove only null and "" values.

Comment: actually. `@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` works fine into my code and as per documentation version 2.x+ the syntax for this annotation is: `@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`  and you are also use `2.6.0`. it should work. can you upgrade the version to `2.8.8`, may be it works.

Comment: Finally I m getting Answer `<dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId> <version>1.5.0</version> </dependency>` add this jar and Use Annotation `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)` . Here i am importing `import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;`