# conversion empty map fail with jackson

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I use spring boot 2, In a dto have

```
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY, content=Include.NON_NULL)
private Map<String, String> settings;
```

I get this error

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
>   `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no
>   String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String
>   value (''); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one
>   Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value ('')

from the client when i check what is sent, i see

```
settings: ""
```

why i get this error?

Edit

```
public Map<String, String> getSettings() {
    settings = settings == null ? new LinkedHashMap<>() : settings;
    return settings;
}

public void setSettings(Map<String, String> settings) {
    this.settings = new LinkedHashMap<>(settings);
}
```

web part

transfort come from: https://github.com/dominicbarnes/form-serialize

var form = transForm.serialize('#form');
form = JSON.stringify(form);

Tried to add on the field

```
@JsonInclude(value=JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter=FilterMap.class)
```

My class

```
public class FilterMap {

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
     return true;
   }
}
```

same problem

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null

Comment: useless, same error...

Comment: Can you post the code to populate "settings" before it is serialized to Json?