# Ignoring Json property if not present in constructor in java

Tags: java, json

I have a class as show below:-

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Response extends ResponseMessage {

    @JsonProperty("ResponseDto")
    private myDTo myDto;

    @JsonProperty("revId")
    private Long revisionId;

    @JsonProperty("modelId")
    private Long model;

    public Response(HttpStatus status, String message) {
        super(status, message);
    }

    public Response(HttpStatus status, String message, Long revisionId) {
        super(status, message);
        this.revisionId = revisionId;
    }

    public Response(HttpStatus status, String message, Long revisionId, Long modelId) {
        super(status, message);
        this.revisionId = revisionId;
        this.model = modelId;
    }

    public Response(HttpStatus status, String message, myDTo myDto) {
        super(status, message);
        this.myDto = myDto;
    }
}
```

Now when i am return the Response class as response as shown below:-

```
return new Response(HttpStatus.OK,"done",123);
```

It return the response json as:-

```
{
"revId":123,
"status":"OK",
"modelId":null,
"message":"done"
}
```

but the want the response to be depend on the constructor which is being called. which in this case should be :-

```
{
"revId":123,
"status":"OK",
"message":"done"
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think here is what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null

Comment: You can use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` for ignore null fields.