# Exclude empty objects, empty arrays and arrays of empty objects from json response

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

## Goal

How can I exclude all empty json objects `{}`, arrays `[]` or arrays of empty objects `[{},{}]` from the JSON response produced by Jackson in a `RestController` ?

## Requirements and context

I'm building a Spring Boot REST API for a client. 
The API sends requests to a database and must produce a JSON response.

#### Constraints:

- The DAO layer sends native SQL queries and receives huge DB results as a List. Developers have to manually map this result to Java objects using indexes (see code below)
- SQL queries return a lot of null values (these queries can NOT be modified). Because of these null values, Java objects having only null-valued fields are frequently instantiated

#### Requirements:

- All fields having null value must be excluded from JSON responses. Already implemented using Jackson `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation
- All empty json objects `{}` or arrays `[]`, or arrays of empty objects `[{},{}]` must be excluded from the JSON response. This is where I'm stuck (Please see example below)

## Code

Manual mapping in DAO layer:

```
public List<A> daoMethod() {
    List<Object[]> dbResult = getDbResults();
    List<A> javaObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    // build nested Java objects
    for (Object[] line in dbResult) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setProp1(line[0]);
        a.setProp2(line[1]);
        // and so on...
        javaObjects.add(a);
        return javaObjects ;
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
public ResponseEntity<A> controllerMethod() {
    List<A> javaObjects = myDao.daoMethod();
    return new ResponseEntity(javaObjects, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

All DTO classes which must be serialized in the JSON response extend the `BaseDto` class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) // removes all fields having NULL value
public abstract class BaseDto implements Serializable{
    // some properties...
}
```

## Actual and expected results

Current JSON output:

```
{
  prop1: "some string",
  prop2: [{},{},{}],
  prop3: [],
  prop4: {},
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  prop1: "some string"
}
```

Comment: please refer the following link **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-nullhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null**

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem. I also tried JsonInclude.NON_EMPTY,JsonInclude.NON_NULL but without any luck

Comment: Any one got solution for this ??

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [NON_EMPTY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY)

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

> Value that indicates that only properties with null value, or what is considered empty, are not to be included.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using this annotation with different combinations (class level, type level...) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`NON_EMPTY` can be used in `application.properties` to exclude empty objects (including null objects) in response.

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_EMPTY
```

By the way `NON_NULL` is also applicable to remove null objects only in response.