# Jackson marshal XMLAttribute gets "null" value

Tags: jaxb, annotations, jackson, xml-attribute

I have an issue with JAXB / Jackson marshalling. I have such an annotation

```java
@XmlAttribute(name = "private")
protected Boolean mPrivate;
```

and I expect that this attribute be absent if the `mPrivate` variable is `null`.

This works fine if the output is XML. But if I switch to JSON, using Jackson, the output is

```
xxxxxxx, "private":null, xxxxxxxx
```

Anybody has an idea why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jackson is compatible with the JAXB annotations. Hence JAXB doesn't support default values for XmlAttributes as the default behavior is to leave them out if value is *null* when serializing to XML.

There are a few options to achieve this for JSON.

1. You can annotate your POJO with 
   @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
2. You can set the default behavior of the ObjectMapper to exclude null-values from serialisation. You do so by calling:

   setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);

   ...on the ObjectMapper instance.

Comment: I discovered that @JsonSerialize can be added at the class level or the field/method level. If applied at the class level, you can still override at the field/method level.