# How ObjectMapper maps JSON string fields with POJO attributes

Tags: jakarta-ee

How ObjectMapper maps JSON string fields with POJO attributes. If particular field(key) in the JSON String missing ?

Comment: Are you using Jackson?  I believe ObjectMapper is Jackson.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I did some google and debug my code then found: 
If key is missing in JSON String objectMapper object will automatically set correponding property to null and read it with the getter method defined in POJO.
If key's value is NULL then ObjectMapper read setter method correponding to the field from the POJO.
Please correct me if I have wrong understanding ....

Comment: The "how" depends highly on how you configure it. See [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null).