# Getter nullpointer without calling it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with `nullPointer` in getter method.

Here is the code:

```
 public String getTitle()
  {
    if(!title.isEmpty())
        return title;
    else 
        return "foo";
  }
```

When I change this to normal getter it works perfectly.

```
public String getTitle()
  {
    return title;
  }
```

Where is the trick? Is there a reflection trick?

**UPDATE
The problem is not null checking, but excecuting getter without calling it**

STACKTRACE

`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)     (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-  >si.mikropis.webkiosk.model.vao.wine.Wine["title"])`

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at si.mikropis.webkiosk.model.vao.base.BaseModel.getTitle(BaseModel.java:41)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:483)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:418)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    ... 32 more`

Comment: I would post your complete stack trace.

Comment: Please add your IDE (Netbeans, Android SDK, ...), included libraries (log4j, AndroidAnnotations, ...) and used frameworks as well (e.g. Hibernate, Struts, ...).

Comment: I'm using jersey and jackson.

Comment: @Trinimon I posted the stacktrace, I guess is jackson and jersey problem, because I'm using restful services.

Comment: Note the BeanPropertyWriter which will use the bean conventions as I've outlined below

Comment: @BrianAgnew So what do you suggest?

Comment: @extra90: as the JSON parser has to run through all members of the object, it might be that there is no way out. Only solutions I can think of is either you tell Jackson not to include `null` values (check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null) or you try to include a custom mapper (see for instance http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers); if you care about performance I'd go for gson anyway (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)

Comment: @extra90 - you have multiple solutions below for handling the null. I would however investigate *why* you have the null. Obviously 'title' isn't being set, and that's a *different* matter/question/subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I note specifically your comment *re. not calling the getter*. Lots of frameworks use the [JavaBean convention](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm), such that if you specify a property `title`, the framework will *call* `getTitle()`.

e.g. in Spring (not implying you're *using* Spring):

```
<property name="title" value="abc"/>
```

would call your setter implicitly.

So you're right to suggest there's some reflection going on. I suspect you're referencing the title property somewhere, and whatever framework in use is invoking your getter implicitly. As noted, you likely have a possible NPE in your getter. A breakpoint will tell you precisely how it's being invoked. Or, in fact, your exception stacktrace.

EDIT: I note your stacktrace, and in particular:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:483)
```

which suggests such reflection is being used.

Comment: The setTitle comes later, I get NPE at the start, when the object is created. I' m not using spring.

Comment: @Brian: even though this explains why the getter is called, it does not explain why the first one should not work. I do not know any framework that depends on the implemntation of a getter ...

Comment: @extra90 - I'm not suggesting you're using Spring. But I am suggesting that frameworks work like that, and nominating a property will result in the corresponding setter/getter being invoked

Answer (score 10):

Check, if `title` is null as well:

```
  public String getTitle()
  {
    if(title != null && !title.isEmpty())
        return title;
    else 
        return "foo";
  }
```

**p.s.** *additional comment as per updated issue*: as the JSON parser has to run through all members of the object, it might be that there is no simple way out. Only solutions I can think of is either to tell Jackson [not to include null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null) or to [implement a custom mapper](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers); if performance is the manin concern I'd go for [google-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) as their library is quite ast and less memory consuming than Jackson.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the getter is excecuting without calling it.

Comment: @extra90 Set a breakpoint in it and check the stack trace when it's executed.

Comment: I think that this *doesn't* address the OP's issue wrt. the getter not being called *explicitly*

Comment: @extra90: what do you mean exactly by "executing without calling it"? Do you use any kind of framework, that might invoke the getter?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson When the object is created, the getter is executed. Don't know why?

Comment: @Extra90 - see my answer re. JavaBean conventions

Comment: @Brian: I assumed that issue is based on a NPE in the getter; there is no reflection trick.

Comment: @Trinimon Null cheks are ok, but calling getter without explicity calling it can slow down performance.

Comment: @extra90: that's true :) - it's very important to know which kind of framework/container you are using. I'm 100% sure this wouldn't happen in a simple Java program.  Brian gave you a good example of what could happen. But Spring is only one example and there are many other frameworks that use JavaBeans and Reflection as well (e.g. ORM frameworks: Hibernate, ORMLite; MVC frameworks: Struts, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Here in the  line

```
  if(!title.isEmpty())
```

`title` is `null`.

Please add `null` check.But checking in getter is a not a good idea.  instead

```
String title  ="foo"

public String getTitle()
  {
    return title;
  }

public String setTitle(String title)
    {
    this.title = title;
    }
```

Comment: I think that this doesn't address the OP's issue wrt. the getter not being called *explicitly*

Comment: @BrianAgnew Ya,I added that as a suggestion,after I addressed the problem in my first lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you do these null/empty checks a lot, it may be worth to include [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultIfBlank%28T,%20T%29).

```
 return StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(title, "foo");
```

Null-safe and handles Unicode whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!title.isEmpty())
```

You are directly performing operations on title without checking whether it is null or not. You must do NPE check first

```
if(title != null) {
if(!title.isEmpty())
    return title;
 } 
 return "foo";
```

Comment: I was not giving the code for that getTitle() I was just trying to stress NPE check. Anyway edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

your `title` object is null and hence calling `isEmpty` on it throws null pointer exception.

The `title` is null even in the second alternative but as you are not calling any method on it hence it does not throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Title might be `null`.

```
public String getTitle() {
    if(title !=null && !title.isEmpty())
        return title;
    else 
        return "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively define title as:
String title = "";

Answer (score 0):

personally I'd use [ternary](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm) operations here

```
public String getTitle() {
   return (title !=null && !title.isEmpty()) ? title : "foo";
}
```

Apart from that I'd say all other answers give you want you want.