# Setting default values to null fields when mapping with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to map some JSON objects to Java objects with Jackson. Some of the fields in the JSON object are mandatory(which I can mark with `@NotNull`) and some are optional.

After the mapping with Jackson, all the fields that are not set in the JSON object will have a null value in Java. Is there a similar annotation to `@NotNull` that can tell Jackson to set a default value to a Java class member, in case it is null?

Edit:
To make the question more clear here is some code example.

The Java object:

```
class JavaObject {
    @NotNull
    public String notNullMember;

    @DefaultValue("Value")
    public String optionalMember;
}
```

The JSON object can be either:

```
{
    "notNullMember" : "notNull"
}
```

or:

```
{
    "notNullMember" : "notNull",
    "optionalMember" : "optional"
}
```

The `@DefaultValue` annotations is just to show what I am asking. It's not a real annotation. If the JSON object is like in the first example I want the value of the `optionalMember` to be `"Value"` and not `null`. Is there an annotation that does such a thing?

Comment: I am looking similar question but for final field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910849/3798662 check this and then mark it as your answer if it solves the purpose

Answer (score 112, accepted):

There is no annotation to set default value.
You can set default value only on java class level:

```
public class JavaObject 
{
    public String notNullMember;

    public String optionalMember = "Value";
}
```

Comment: This gives a default value if there is no json for the optionalMember. If there is json setting it to "null", it will be null, not "Value"

Comment: Added an answer showing how to save `Value` in case of `null`

Comment: Also, if the class have an AllArgsConstructor, the default value will be erased to null
See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48725922/9640261

Comment: @LeeMeador, maybe because the value, in that case, is "null"?

Comment: @llya not working in jackson 2.10, any suggestion ???

Comment: try this ; more simpler & cleaner way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910849/3798662

Answer (score 54):

Only one proposed solution keeps the `default-value` when `some-value:null` was set explicitly (POJO readability is lost there and it's clumsy)

Here's how one can keep the `default-value` and never set it to `null`

```
@JsonProperty("some-value")
public String someValue = "default-value";

@JsonSetter("some-value")
public void setSomeValue(String s) {
    if (s != null) { 
        someValue = s; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do it for all fields of class?

Comment: This should be the accepted solution

Comment: No. Sir! This code make you POJO NOT be pure. Please don't do that.

Comment: try much cleaner way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910849/3798662

Answer (score 21):

Use the [`JsonSetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html%3Cbr/%3E) annotation with the value [`Nulls.SKIP`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/Nulls.html#SKIP)

If you want to assign a default value to any param which is not set in json request then you can simply assign that in the POJO itself.

If you don't use `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)` then the default value will be initialised only if there is no value coming in JSON, but if someone explicitly put a null then it can lead to a problem. Using `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)` will tell the Json de-searilizer to avoid `null` initialisation.

> Value that indicates that an input null value should be skipped and the default assignment is to be made; **this usually means that the property will have its default value**.

as follow:

```
public class User {
    @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)
    private Integer Score = 1000;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is excellent...if only it worked with lombok.

Comment: It totally works!

Comment: it works perfect if the value is null, but how to manage if the value is empty?

Comment: I am using this suggestion on a static inner class, and it is compatible with lombok, at least that way.

Answer (score 11):

There is a solution, if you use Lombok's Builder annotation, you can combine Lombok with Jackson via the [@Jacksonized](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) annotation.

Without this, the combination of Lombok and Jackson is not working for this.

Via adding the `@Builder.Default` on the property you are then able to set default values.

```html
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class SomeClass {

     String field1;
     
     @Builder.Default
     String field2 = "default-value";

}
```

So, in the incoming json request, if the field2 is not specified, then the Builder.default annotation will allow the Builder interface to set the specified default-value into the property, if not, the original value from the request is set into that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

You can create your own JsonDeserializer and annotate that property with `@JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultZero.class)`

For example: To configure BigDecimal to default to ZERO:

```
public static class DefaultZero extends JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> {
    private final JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> delegate;

    public DefaultZero(JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return jsonParser.getDecimalValue();
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
class Sth {

   @JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultZero.class)
   BigDecimal property;
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910849/3798662

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the solution is to set the value of the properties inside the default constructor. So in this case the java class is:

```
class JavaObject {

    public JavaObject() {

        optionalMember = "Value";
    }

    @NotNull
    public String notNullMember;

    public String optionalMember;
}
```

After the mapping with Jackson, if the `optionalMember` is missing from the JSON its value in the Java class is `"Value"`.

However, I am still interested to know if there is a solution with annotations and without the default constructor.

Comment: But if the JSON has value null, the optionalMember will end up as null. That may be what is wanted or not.

Comment: This is the same as just setting the default value on a field. Doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make the member private and add a setter/getter pair.
In your setter, if null, then set default value instead.
Additionally, I have shown the snippet with the getter also returning a default when internal value is null.

```
class JavaObject {
    private static final String DEFAULT="Default Value";

    public JavaObject() {
    }

    @NotNull
    private String notNullMember;
    public void setNotNullMember(String value){
            if (value==null) { notNullMember=DEFAULT; return; }
            notNullMember=value;
            return;
    }

    public String getNotNullMember(){
            if (notNullMember==null) { return DEFAULT;}
            return notNullMember;
    }

    public String optionalMember;
}
```

Comment: Setter set non-null value, so getter value will go in if statement each time it is called if and only if notNullMember is never set

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [InjectableValues](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/InjectableValues.html) and [@JacksonInject](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonInject.html). It is very useful if you need to use not always the same value but one get from DB or somewhere else for the specific case. Here is an example of using `JacksonInject`:

```java
protected static class Some {
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;

    public Some(@JsonProperty("field1") final String field1,
            @JsonProperty("field2") @JacksonInject(value = "defaultValueForField2",
                    useInput = OptBoolean.TRUE) final String field2) {
        this.field1 = requireNonNull(field1);
        this.field2 = requireNonNull(field2);
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
}

@Test
public void testReadValueInjectables() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final InjectableValues injectableValues =
            new InjectableValues.Std().addValue("defaultValueForField2", "somedefaultValue");
    mapper.setInjectableValues(injectableValues);

    final Some actualValueMissing = mapper.readValue("{\"field1\": \"field1value\"}", Some.class);
    assertEquals(actualValueMissing.getField1(), "field1value");
    assertEquals(actualValueMissing.getField2(), "somedefaultValue");

    final Some actualValuePresent =
            mapper.readValue("{\"field1\": \"field1value\", \"field2\": \"field2value\"}", Some.class);
    assertEquals(actualValuePresent.getField1(), "field1value");
    assertEquals(actualValuePresent.getField2(), "field2value");
}
```

Keep in mind that if you are using constructor to create the entity (this usually happens when you use [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) or [@AllArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) in [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) ) and you put `@JacksonInject` not to the constructor but to the property it will not work as expected - value of the injected field will always override value in json, no matter whether you put `useInput = OptBoolean.TRUE` in `@JacksonInject`. This is because jackson injects those properties after constructor is called (even if the property is `final`) - field is set to the correct value in constructor but then it is overrided (check: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2678 and https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1528#issuecomment-607725333 for more information), this test is unfortunately *passing*:

```java
protected static class Some {
    private final String field1;

    @JacksonInject(value = "defaultValueForField2", useInput = OptBoolean.TRUE)
    private final String field2;

    public Some(@JsonProperty("field1") final String field1,
            @JsonProperty("field2") @JacksonInject(value = "defaultValueForField2",
                    useInput = OptBoolean.TRUE) final String field2) {
        this.field1 = requireNonNull(field1);
        this.field2 = requireNonNull(field2);
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
}

@Test
public void testReadValueInjectablesIncorrectBehavior() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final InjectableValues injectableValues =
            new InjectableValues.Std().addValue("defaultValueForField2", "somedefaultValue");
    mapper.setInjectableValues(injectableValues);

    final Some actualValueMissing = mapper.readValue("{\"field1\": \"field1value\"}", Some.class);
    assertEquals(actualValueMissing.getField1(), "field1value");
    assertEquals(actualValueMissing.getField2(), "somedefaultValue");

    final Some actualValuePresent =
            mapper.readValue("{\"field1\": \"field1value\", \"field2\": \"field2value\"}", Some.class);
    assertEquals(actualValuePresent.getField1(), "field1value");
    // unfortunately "field2value" is overrided because of putting "@JacksonInject" to the field
    assertEquals(actualValuePresent.getField2(), "somedefaultValue");
}
```

Another approach is to use `JsonDeserializer`, e.g.:

```java
    public class DefaultValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
                throws IOException {
            return jsonParser.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public String getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
            return "some random value that can be different each time: " + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    }
```

and then annotate a field like that:

```java
    public class Content {
        @JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultValueDeserializer.class)
        private String someField;
...
    }
```

keep in mind that you can use attributes in `getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt)` passed using

```java
mapper.reader().forType(SomeType.class).withAttributes(singletonMap("dbConnection", dbConnection)).readValue(jsonString);
```

like that:

```java
        @Override
        public String getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
            return ((DbConnection)ctxt.getAttribute("dbConnection")).getDefaultValue(...);
        }
```

Hope this helps to someone with a similar problem.

P.S. I'm using jackson v. 2.9.6

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case the default value was in database. Below is the solution for that:

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfiguration {
 @Autowired
 private AppConfigDao appConfigDao;

 @Bean
 public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder() {
   Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
       .deserializerByType(SomeDto.class, 
 new SomeDtoJsonDeserializer(appConfigDao.findDefaultValue()));
   return builder;
 }
```

Then in `SomeDtoJsonDeserializer` use `ObjectMapper` to deserialize the json and set default value if your field/object is null.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a lot of good suggestions, but here's one more. You can use @JsonDeserialize to perform an arbitrary "sanitizer" which Jackson will invoke post-deserialization:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter=Message1._Sanitizer.class)  
public class Message1 extends MessageBase
{
    public String string1 = "";
    public int integer1;

    public static class _Sanitizer extends StdConverter<Message1,Message1> {
        @Override
        public Message1 convert(Message1 message) {
            if (message.string1 == null) message.string1 = "";
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to the entire class using Jackson > 2. This will ignore null fields.

> Value that indicates that only properties with non-null values are to be included.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Foo
{
  String bar;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761975/5806870