# Jackson deserialize default values missing

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, lombok

I try to deserialize a JSON object that I receive in my API using the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ExampleDto ed = mapper.readValue(req.body(), ExampleDto.class);
```

My class uses Lombok to generate constructors, getters and setters, and looks like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExampleDto {
    private String name = "";
    private List<String> values = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

Both properties should be optional, and use the default value specified in the class definition if they are not provided. However, if I now try to deserialize the JSON

```
{name: "Foo"}
```

the `values` field is `null`. From my understanding, and all example code I found, `values` should be an empty list.

Edit: Not a duplicate, as I'm using Lombok without Optionals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit default values when deserializing JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928841/implicit-default-values-when-deserializing-json-using-jackson)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@AllArgsConstructor` creates the following constructor

```
@ConstructorProperties({"name", "values"})
ExampleDto(String name, List<String> values) {
    this.name = name;
    this.values = values;
}
```

The constructor is annotated with  `@ConstructorProperties` which means a property-based creator (argument-taking constructor or factory method) is available to instantiate values from JSON object so jackson-databind uses this constructor to instantiate an object from `ExampleDto` class.

When the following line executes

```
mapper.readValue("{\"name\": \"Foo\"}", ExampleDto.class);
```

because there's no value for `values` in the provided JSON, `null` is passed for the second argument when the constructor is invoked.

If you remove `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation jackson-databind would use setter methods to initialize the object and in this case `values` would not be `null`

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I always hate this kind of problem. Even now that I know the issue it's quite hard to find additional information

Comment: And if we want to keep @AllArgsConstructor ?? How we can tell Jackson to not use this all args constructor ?

Comment: @user2668735 You can keep `@AllArgsConstructor` with `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @_(@JsonIgnore))`, and make sure to include a default constructor