# How to override Lombok Setter methods

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using lombok in my project and generation `Setters` and `Getters` using `@Setters` and `@Getters` annotations on top of POJO class. I'm trying to override setters method of a property but it's not working

I want to check if JSON property is Empty or Null i want to set default value in Setter method

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@ToString
public class DefaultModel {


private String name;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)private String age;    

public void setAge(String age) {
     if(age==null||age.trim().isEmpty()||age.equals("null")) {
        this.age="10";
    }else {
        this.age=age;
    }
}

}
```

Working scenarios:

```
        {
"name":"some",
"age":null
     }

     {
"name":"some",
"age":"null"
     }

    {
"name":"some",
"age":"  "
     }
```

Failed Scenario :

```
    {
"name":"some"
    }
```

Output:

```
DefaultModel(name=some, age=null)
```

And i'm following this as reference also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139678/lombok-how-to-customise-getter-for-boolean-object-field), but no luck so far

Comment: Unrelated: maybe you check `age` to be != null **before** you call `isEmpty()` on it ...

Comment: Also unrelated: why is your `age` attribute a `String`?

Comment: Not so unrelated: `age.equals(null)` - this test will either return `false` or throw a `NullPointerException` (this is related to @GhostCat 's comment).

Comment: @GhostCat Lombok does dark magic in form of undocumented compiler-API calls. As far as I know, they work on the AST, but I do not know whether they delete existing nodes (e.g. existing setters).

Comment: but really this is all insane, how about if i use lombok getters and setters variable level, i mean deleting on top of class and declare on each variable if required?

Comment: @Deadpool do you ever set the name in the failed scenario? If so how?

Comment: Unrelated: You should use `@Data` instead of annotating with `@Getter` and `@Setter`. @Data is a shortcut for those and includes `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Either you just hit a bug I've never seen or you're testing it wrong.

An annotation like

```
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE) private String age;
```

on the field level indeed stops the setter from being generated. But given that you're defining a setter, you don't even need it. An explicit `@Setter` stops the generation, too.

I've just tried your example using Eclipse 4.7.3a and Lombok 1.18.0 and your (buggy) setter gets called. I've been using Lombok a lot over a few years and never encountered such a bug.

*Most probably the problem is that your JSON deserializer does not use setters at all.* I guess, you're testing something like

```
DefaultModel defaultModel = deserialize("{\"name\":\"some\"}", DefaultModel.class);
```

instead of testing the setter directly. And that's the problem.

Comment: @Deadpool No idea how postman works, but I'd bet it uses no setters. GSON doesn't use them either.

Comment: @maaartinus agree with you, That's why asked @Deadpool (OP) if he/she ever set the name in the failed scenario (call the setter)... because I [**tested**](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/settertest) it too and it works the thing with the `null` is a serialization/deserialization issue, not related at all with loombok.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i agree with you it's problem with deserialization of missing fields in JSON body

Answer (score 0):

It possible that JSON deserializer uses constructor generated by Lombok (not setters).

Have a look here:
[Jackson deserialize default values missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725922/jackson-deserialize-default-values-missing)