# How can I configure a Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize certain fields of certain beans with a custom value if they are null?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class that belongs to a third-party library that I don't have access to. It looks like:

```
public class Product {

    private String thumbnailUrl;    

   // many other properties, some of which are POJOs or collections

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

This is only one of the classes that I am going to serialize into string using Jackson. There are quite a few others.

The `thumbnailUrl` property can sometimes be `null`. How can I configure an `ObjectMapper` to serialize this field as `http://www.example.com/unknown.png`, if it is `null`?

I think I cannot use [mixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) as mixins won't have access to the original object hence they can't check if the value of the property is `null` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`private String thumbnailUrl = "http://my.default.url";`

As the OP mentioned in the comments, the class comes from a third-party library, so modifying it (a'la [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805455/setting-default-values-to-null-fields-when-mapping-with-jackson)) or annotating (a'la [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields)) is not an option. In this case you have two options left:

- Patch the third-party lib (apparently you have access to the source ;))
- Hack your way around it in the custom serializer (needs to be properly tested though, and this quick hack wouldn't work in multi-threaded environments)

As in:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Product value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    boolean revert = false;
    if (value.thumbnailUrl == null) {
      value.thumbnailUrl = "http://my.default.url";
      revert = true;
    }
    jgen.writeObject(value);
    if (revert) {
      value.thumbnailUrl = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this is a third party class and I don't have access to the source code. I want to externalize this logic.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to write your own serializer for this class. There are numerous how-to for that, e.g., http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization of course you won't be able to annotate the class, but still can configure your ObjectMapper to use your custom serializer for the class (also in the linked how-to)

Comment: I can write a custom serializer, but I want all aspects of serialization to remain as is, and only customize serialization of this field. If I write a custom serializer for a POJO that has 20 fields and add serialization logic for all the 20 fields, that would be terrible.

Comment: Yes, but you could hack it around, I'll update my answer, give me a couple minutes please.

Comment: This won't work in my case, as changing value of the thumbnail property will have unwanted side effects (e.g. listeners getting triggered, etc.) I am marking this answer as accepted though (until someone comes up with a better solution).

Comment: As a hack-hack you could do a (deep)copy of the object being serialized, and then listeners won't be triggered because the original object won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution but it is not as simple as I was expecting it to be:

```
@Test
public void shouldSerializeDefaultThumbnailUrlIfThumbnailUrlIsNull() throws Exception {
    // Given
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setPrimaryKey("123");

    PropertyFilter filter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
        @Override
        public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
            if (pojo.getClass().equals(Product.class)
                    && ((Product) pojo).getThumbnailUrl() == null
                    && writer.getName().equals("thumbnailUrl")) {
                jgen.writeStringField(writer.getName(), "http://www.example.com/default.png");
            } else {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, prov);
            }
        }
    };

    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("thumbnailFilter", filter);

    this.mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
    String json = this.mapper.writeValueAsString(p);

    assertThat(json, equalTo("{\"thumbnailUrl\":\"http://www.example.com/default.png\",\"id\":\"123\"}"));
}
```

---

Ignore this. It doesn't work in my case as my class needs to be annotated which I can't.

Comment: If I could implement a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` for the `Product` class that was identical to the default serializer but had this rule only for this particular field, that would be much nicer.

Comment: That would indeed be nice, but I haven't found a nice, easy way to do exactly that.