# Can Jackson/Jax-rs have an optional data?

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I am making a curl request to endpoint with following option curl --data {"foo" : "bar"} for POST request

However I want to implement a default behavior for missing data, ie curl without --data should also work for POST request.

Currently if data is missing it returns: "error":400,"errorCode":"INVALID_JSON". I do not want that.

1. Is it possible ?
2. Does it have any annotation to support optional data.?

Comment: How are you defining your resource?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting default values to null fields when mapping with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805455/setting-default-values-to-null-fields-when-mapping-with-jackson)