# How do you specify default values for Jackson deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/getUser")
public JSONObject getContent(@ReqeustBody User user)
```

Up here is my Controller code.

```
@Data
public class User{
    private String username = "administrator";
    private String password = "123456";   
    private Integer age = 18;
}
```

Up here is my `User` class code.

```
{
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"000",
    "age":""
}
```

When I `POST` the `JSON` above, I get the `age` property to be `null`.

I want `Jackson` to deserialize the empty fields (`""` or `null`) in `JSON` with default values.

Like this:

```
{
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"000",
    "age":18
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805455/setting-default-values-to-null-fields-when-mapping-with-jackson)

Comment: It is strange that the age field is initialized but as far as I understand in the response it is missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a custom getter property where setting your default value in case of `null`.

```
   public Integer getAge() {
        if (age == null) {
            return 18;
        } else {
            return this.age;
        }
    }
```

Note that you can't change the `setAge` method because it is not invoked in this case, infact there is no `age` field that will inform Jackson to call that method.

---

An alternative is to use a custom constructor and use the [`JsonSetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) annotation with the value [`Nulls.SKIP`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/Nulls.html#SKIP)

> Value that indicates that an input null value should be skipped and no assignment is to be made; **this usually means that the property will have its default value**.

as follow:

```
 public class User {
    @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)
    private Integer age;

    public User() {
        this.age = 18;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

The `@JsonSetter` is present in package `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` and can be imported as dependency in maven using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>YOURVERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I didn't find the `JsonSetter` annotation that I could write on the field, `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter` is only allowed on `class` and `method` .

Comment: @Michael it is present in the package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation. Check the updated answer for details

Comment: Thank you Davide, my version is 2.8.0, it can't be written on a `field`.

Comment: @Michael correct, as the comment in the source code suggests
`// ^^^ allowed on Fields, (constructor) parameters since 2.9`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`JsonSetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) annotation with the value [`Nulls.SKIP`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/Nulls.html#SKIP)

> Value that indicates that an input null value should be skipped and the default assignment is to be made; **this usually means that the property will have its default value**.

As follows:

```java
     public class User {
        @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)
        private Integer Score = 1000;
        ...
    }
```

---

usually, if you don't use `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)` then the default value will be initialized if there is no value coming in JSON, but if someone explicitly put a null then it can lead to problem. Using `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)` will tell the Json de-searilizer to avoid `null` initialization.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make you `setAge` to handle the `null` case, for example:

```
 void setAge(Integer age){
   if(age!=null) this.age = age;
 }
```

Or you can have a look at `@JsonSetter(nulls=Nulls.SKIP)`, I just looked at the source code, I haven't tried :(

Hope that helps.

Comment: The setAge doesn't work because there is no age field. If there was an age field with a null value it could work, but not in absence of the field age.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Ah I just saw the `@Data` annotation from lombok ( I assume),  so there is no setter there. This is actually a bit tricky, but its java's nature, even there is no setter, the client code can still change the object's field value by using reflection which I assume thats how jackson does it.  I think your answer makes sense in the context that you still wanna use `@Data`.