# Springboot: Can DTO be changed at runtime with null values not being present in the object returned from api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, entity, dto

I have a springboot application which is hitting raw api's of the datasource. Now suppose I have a Customer entity with approx 50 fields and I have a raw api for it in which I pass names of the columns and I get the values for that column. Now I am implementing api in springboot which consumes raw api.

I need to implement different api's in springboot for different combinations of the fields of Customer entity and return only those fields setted in object for which user had queried and remove the null valued fields from the object. One way is to implement different dto's for different combinations of the columns of Customer entity. Is there any other way to implement the same in which I don't need to define different dto's for different combinations of the columns of Customer entity in Spring boot ???

Comment: This could be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707165/spring-rest-service-how-to-configure-to-remove-null-objects-in-json-response

Comment: If you annotate your DTO class with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`, null fields will not show up in JSON.

Comment: Take a look no this solution: [setting-default-values-to-null-fields-when-mapping-with-jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805455/setting-default-values-to-null-fields-when-mapping-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the `ObjectMapper` directly, or make use of the `@JsonInclude` annotation:

```java
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

`OR`

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public Customer() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

You can see how to do it with this sample code:

```java
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(1L);
customer.setName("Vikas");
customer.setEmail("info@vikas.com");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
String valueAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customer);
```

Since the password is left `null`, you will have an object that does not exist password.

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Vikas",
  "email": "info@vikas.com"
}
```

Comment: I need to return the same string that you had returned in variable valueAsString. But I need to return it as a object and not as string.

Answer (score 0):

with Jackson 2.0 serialization you can specify data inclusion on non nulls at different levels, i.e. on the object mapper (with constructor options), the DTO class or DTO class fields (with annotations).
[See Jackson annotations here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using @JsonInclude inside the DTO class. Please refer following code block for ignoring null values.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) // ignoring null values 
@Data //lombock
@Builder //builder pattern 
public class Customer {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```