# Spring/Kotlin: How do I make a missing JSON field deserialize to the default value given by my entity class, and not to null?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I have an entity, defined using a data class:

```
@Entity
data class BlogPost(

    (...)

    val title: String,

    (...)

    val slug: String = title.toSlug(),

)
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806773), I expected that a JSON object without a `slug` field would deserialize to a `BlogPost` whose slug was created using my `.toSlug()` extension method – but, to my surprise, the deserialized `.slug` ends up being `null` *even though* I thought it wasn't nullable (it's a `String`, not a `String?`).

I've tried using `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`, but I suspect this is the wrong tactic, and it only seems to affect serialization; the missing JSON value is still deserialized to `null` rather than my default.

I'm on Spring Boot 2.4.3.

Comment: Could you give a complete runnable example?

Comment: An example would help, but I'm guessing something like JPA or Jackson creating the object and is using reflection to bypass the default value. You can either check and set the correct value using the `copy` function on the data class when relevant or add a getter that checks for null and returns the default.