# java jackson set default value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Java and Jackson library to parse a JSON file to a Java class. My problem is that I can't set a default value if the value is null or empty. Is it possible to do it? For now, I just write it in the setters section.

For example, I have a JSON file

```json
{"CountryCode": "",
  "sourceName": "",
  "from": "type1",
  "to": "type2"}
```

And in my Java class I would like to set the value to some Java function if it is null or empty.

For example

```java
public class ExClass{
    @JsonProperty("CountryCode")
    private String countryCode = "USA";
}
```

So, if the value is set, then it will be it. If it is not, then it should be USA.

Comment: see [Setting default values to null fields when mapping with Jackson](//stackoverflow.com/q/18805455)

Comment: @Tom I have tried but it is not working.

Comment: @Vova What do you mean? What did you try? And what were the results? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: It doesn't work because country code is not null, but is empty string. Try to use @JsonSetter to implement the method that will handle null or empty string

Comment: @mpdgr could you desribe how to do this in right way? Thank you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i tried to set    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) for class. And result was that value were empty instead of default value. Also tried to set         @JsonSetter(contentNulls = JsonSetter.Nulls.AS_EMPTY) but it just skips it and set the defualt value in any way.

Comment: I thought about exactly the same solution Rakib descibed below

Comment: @mpdgr so the only way its the defenite the all setters in the pojo class, corect?

Comment: @Vova You could also write your own JSON parser, Jackson allows you to do that and provides tools for doing so. But you don't really want that.

Comment: @mpdgr got you)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make the JSON setter like the below:

```
@JsonSetter("CountryCode")
public void setCountryCode (String countryCode) {
    if (!countryCode.equals(null) && !countryCode.equals("")) { 
        this.countryCode = countryCode; 
    }
}
```

I think it will serve your requirement. If not work, let us know the details.

Ref: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965174/2160443)

Comment: if there some posibility to set it in another way?

Comment: I honestly wonder why those two users chose to upvote an obviously incorrect answer which was taken from another answer, thus making this question a duplicate and although already said "I have tried but it is not working".

Comment: @Tom I upvoted because imo this is exactly the correct answer, can you pls clarify what is wrong with it?

Comment: @mpdgr It is correct to compare String with `!=`?

Comment: Yeah, i gues its better to use isEmpty method for Strings

Comment: @Tom yes, this should be .equals but otherwise the approach is correct isn't it?

Comment: @mpdgr All the other stuff got copied from somewhere else. There is only one thing that got added and that could warrant a reward, but that one thing is wrong.