# How can I get another value like @Getter of lombok?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Is there any annotation to let us get another value if original value is null?

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SomeDto extends BaseDto {

    private BigDecimal a;

    @GetOrAlternative(alternative = "a")
    private BigDecimal b;
```

For example, I want to get value a if b is null on above code.
I want to use that like dto.getBOrAlternative().
Is that possible?
If that is not possible, how can I implement that?

I tried to make custom annotation and processor following this: https://www.happykoo.net/@happykoo/posts/256
However, it didn't work. I think it is because that is not a field level.

Comment: check this link please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805455/setting-default-values-to-null-fields-when-mapping-with-jackson

Comment: You're saying there's no implementation of what I want yet, right?