# Jackson Object Mapper is Not Using the Mapper's setDateFormat, or setSerializationInclusion

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I have written a class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application:

```
@ApplicationPath(value = "/*")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // your classes here
        classes.add(ObjectMapperProvider.class);
        return classes;
     }
}
```

The only purpose of this is to override the default ObjectMapperProvider, and include this class in the Application.

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperProvider() {
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"));
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

I am sure that the extended MyApplication class is being loaded via the web.xml file.

```
<web-app ...>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycomp.somedir.application.MyApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>

...

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mycomp.somedir.application.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

...

</web-app>
```

Ideally, I'd like a central location to keep any kind of formatting for the JSON (this is opposed to have annotations like @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) ).  I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null), and through other S.O. questions that extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application is the way to do this.

Unfortunately, the JSON is still including nulls, as well as the timestamp in ms.  Here's an example:

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "object":{
      "objectId":"25",
      "userId":"user id 22",
      "creationDate":1378843680000,
      "lastUpdatedDate":null,
      "title":"title 2",
      "defaultImg":"http://someurl2",
      "size":3,
      "lastEditDate":1378843680000
   }
```

What is wrong with this setup?  It seems as though it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your whole configuration but the mapper configuration seems to work.

I've tested it lke this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"));
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

and the result from a simple object (with a null field) is:

```
{
    date: "2015.04.28 AD at 23:54:37 CEST"
}
```

so I would say that your Provider is not correctly injected.
I did a lot of tests but I wasn't able to inject it correctly, in my case the `getContext(Class<?> arg0)` wasn't called, and so the ObjectMapper used wasn't the one "customized". : /