# Enable Object Mapper writeValueAsString method to include null values

Tags: java, json, string, serialization, jackson

I have a JSON object which may contain a few `null` values.
I use `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` to convert my JSON object as `String`.

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

If my object contains any field that contains a value as `null`, then that field is not included in the `String` that comes from `writeValueAsString()`.
I want my `ObjectMapper` to give me all fields in the `String` even if their value is `null`.

Example:

```
object = {"name": "John", "id": 10}
json   = {"name": "John", "id": 10}

object = {"name": "John", "id": null}
json   = {"name": "John"}
```

Comment: It depends on the annotations on the type or how the mapper is configured, e.g., see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null).

Answer (score 6):

Jackson should serialize `null` fields to `null` by default. See the following example

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Test());
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    static class Test {
        private String help = "something";
        private String nope = null;

        public String getHelp() {
            return help;
        }

        public void setHelp(String help) {
            this.help = help;
        }

        public String getNope() {
            return nope;
        }

        public void setNope(String nope) {
            this.nope = nope;
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
{
  "help" : "something",
  "nope" : null
}
```

You don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 2):

`Include.ALWAYS` worked for me.
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);

Other possible values for `Include` are:

- `Include.NON_DEFAULT`
- `Include.NON_EMPTY`
- `Include.NON_NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar issue with `SpringBoot`, it could miss the getter function for the entity class.

I included `@Getter` in spring entity class and it was fixed.