# How to prevent NULL values insertion to ObjectNode in jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I want the jackson to ignore the null values when putting them into the instance of ObjectNode. (I know how to prevent nulls when serializing a pojo) Here i am manually putting the the key/values in ObjectNode instance and i want the jackson to ignore the key/value to ignore when value is null.

for example

```
objectNode.put("Name", null);
```

should be ignored and does not get inserted to objectNode.

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null?

Comment: @MichałZiober i am not serializing a pojo to json, i am manually constructing a json, so i can not use annotations.

Comment: Could you give me a little example how you are constructing this `JSON`? Good example is better that 1000 words - I think it will help us to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES` feature but before you have to convert your `ObjectNode` object to `Map`.

See below example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);

String nullValue = null;

ObjectNode subNode = new ObjectNode(mapper.getNodeFactory());
subNode.put("test", 1);
subNode.put("nullValue", nullValue);

ObjectNode node = new ObjectNode(mapper.getNodeFactory());
node.put("notNull", "Not null.");
node.put("nullValue", nullValue);
node.set("subNode", subNode);


MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
Object mapValue = mapper.convertValue(node, mapType);

System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mapValue));
```

Above program prints:

```
{
  "notNull" : "Not null.",
  "subNode" : {
    "test" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using jackson v1.9. mapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false); and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. In my example I am using v2.4.1 and `com.fasterxml` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ObjectNode.putNull(FieldName)
```

Answer (score 0):

one can use now

```
objectNode.put("PropName", NullNode.getInstance());
```