# jackson - skip keys with null values while serializing the HashMap object

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

I'm trying to serialize the Java object with hashmap into json string using jackson object mapper.

Below is the class definition of `Ext` -

```java
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Objects;

        @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
        @JsonPropertyOrder({})
        public class Ext implements Serializable {

            @JsonIgnore
            private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap();
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4500317258794294335L;

            public Ext() {
            }

            @JsonAnyGetter
            public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
                return this.additionalProperties;
            }

            @JsonAnySetter
            public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
                this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
            }

            // ignore toString, equals and hascode

            public static class ExtBuilder {
                protected Ext instance;

                public ExtBuilder() {
                    if (this.getClass().equals(Ext.ExtBuilder.class)) {
                        this.instance = new Ext();
                    }
                }

                public Ext build() {
                    Ext result = this.instance;
                    this.instance = null;
                    return result;
                }

                public Ext.ExtBuilder withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
                    this.instance.getAdditionalProperties().put(name, value);
                    return this;
                }
            }
        }
```

Below is the the sample test case -

```java
    @Test
    public void testNullObjectSerialization() throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
        mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(
              JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
        mapper.writeValue(out, new Ext.ExtBuilder().withAdditionalProperty("unexpected", null).withAdditionalProperty("expected", true).build());
        String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"expected\":true}", result);
    }
```

I used

```java
mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(
              JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL));`
```

by using the answer provided in stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282852/how-to-prevent-null-values-insertion-to-objectnode-in-jackson).

I'm expecting the result as `{"expected":true}` but somehow the key with `null` value is included in the result.

How can I fix this issue?

Note:

1. Code is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/jackson-demo).
2. I'm using jacksersion version 2.9.8

Comment: can you remove this `JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS` and try

Comment: If I remove `JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS`, I'm getting compiler error `Cannot resolve method 'construct(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include)'`.

Comment: I tried with both JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL  `mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(
              JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL, JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL));` Still same issue

Comment: I'm guessing it was because of `Map` jackson could not able to find the map properties with null

Answer (score 2):

When you put `@JsonInclude` on a field, that means if the field **(not the element of fields)** is **null** then it will be ignored from conversion.

- **In your case** when you use `@JsonInclude` on `additionalProperties` that means, if `additionalProperties`(**itself**) is null then it will be ignored from conversion.

> **so `@JsonInclude` only checks `additionalProperties` itself for null value, not its elements.**

---

Example: Assume that you have an `Ext` object with `additionalProperties=null`, when you want to serialize it, the `additionalProperties` is ignored because it is **null**.

- But in your scenario the **elements** of the `additionalProperties` map contain **null** and Jackson doesn't ignore them.

---

**Solution 1**

> You can serialize additionalProperties map (itself) not the whole Ext object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        //Create Ext  Object
        Ext ext = new Ext.ExtBuilder().withAdditionalProperty("unexpected", null).withAdditionalProperty("expected", true).build();

        //Config
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        //Conversion the additionalProperties map (ext.getAdditionalProperties())
        String filterMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(ext.getAdditionalProperties());

        //Result ({"expected":true})
        System.out.println(filterMap);


    }
}
```

> Convert JSON to Ext Object

And also you can get `Ext` object from the generated string. in this case, your object has a filtered additionalProperties (does not have any element with null key or null value)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        //Create Ext  Object
        Ext ext = new Ext.ExtBuilder().withAdditionalProperty("unexpected", null).withAdditionalProperty("expected", true).build();

        //Config
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        //Conversion the additionalProperties map (ext.getAdditionalProperties())
        String filterMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(ext.getAdditionalProperties());

        //Result ({"expected":true})
        System.out.println(filterMap);

        //Convert back JSON string to Ext object
        Ext filterdExt = mapper.readValue(filterMap, Ext.class);

        //Print AdditionalProperties of filterdExt ({"expected":true})
        System.out.println(filterdExt.getAdditionalProperties());

    }
```

---

**Solution 2**

You can write a custom serializer.

**[This link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)** might be useful for this purpose

Comment: I tried your solution and I'm still facing same issue

Comment: But I tested it, it was ok and returned {expecte:true}, notice that in my code, I'm converting ext.getAdditionalProperties(), not the entire ext. please check it again.

Comment: I added @JsonInclude and my java Date property that was being skipped when null started to show up. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WriteValue  does not consider inclusion in any way: it only applies to writing of JSON.
Conversion is the sequence of write-then-read; but by time read is done, output does not contain excluded values any more.

Replace this code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
        mapper.writeValue(out, new Ext.ExtBuilder().withAdditionalProperty("unexpected", null).withAdditionalProperty("expected", true).build());
        String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"expected\":true}", result);
```

by

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
            mapper.writeValue(out, mapper.convertValue(new Ext.ExtBuilder().withAdditionalProperty("unexpected", null).withAdditionalProperty("expected", true).build(), Ext.class));

            String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
            Assert.assertEquals("{\"expected\":true}", result);
```

Comment: Look at my new answer.

Comment: i tried new answer as well but it doesn't solve my problem