# Jackson java object to json serialization is not including null fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have two java beans as below:

```
public class Class1 {
   private String field1;
   private Object field2;
   //getter and setter
}
public class Class2 {
  private Map<String,Object> field;
  //getter and setter
}
```

When the object gets serialized to Json, it looks like this:

Class1: When field2 is null

```
{
   field1:"value"
}
```

Class2: when value of map is null

```
{
   field:{"key":null}
}
```

My question is what is the difference between the two? why for Class1 it didn't include null field in json? How do I include null field in json for Class1? I have tried the following but did't work:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class Class1 {
   private String field1;
   private Object field2;
   //getter and setter
}
```

and even tried on field level:

```
public class Class1 {
   private String field1;
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
   private Object field2;
   //getter and setter
}
```

I am using Jersey.

Comment: Have your tried `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`?

Comment: tried, but my requirement is to include null field.

Comment: I think by default it won't include null fields, I tried @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS) to include them in json but it didn't work.

Comment: Yup, sorry my bad. What about customizing your own `ObjectMapper`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25960533/815227) (where it actually makes the contrary of what you follow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Comment: @rkosegi I want to include Null fields. How will it be duplicate question ?

Comment: @Surajhk : if you read it, you should understand that it's actually "How to configure NULL field serialization" - so it is duplicate.

Comment: One more thing: make sure you are not accidentally using Jackson 1.x annotations (from `org.codehaus.jackson.annotation`). Jackson 2.x annotations are in different package (`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`), but since names are same it is possible to sometimes get the two confused if both versions are in classpath (IDE shows both for auto-completion).

Answer (score 2):

The following example is with jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class1 class1 = new Main().new Class1();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(class1));
```

and the output is:

> {"field1":null,"field2":null}