# common dto for two incoming REST json

Tags: java, json, jackson, marshalling, dto

I want to create a common dto like as shown below for receiving the incoming Manager and Staff details from a REST service

```
public class Employee {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("designation")
    public String designation;

    @JsonProperty("item")
    public String item;

    @JsonProperty("item")
    public List<Item> items;

    //setters and getters
}
```

The problem is that for for Manager the item field will be a List where as for Staff it will be a string, so I have created two field for item, one for receiving String and another for List, but its not working and I am getting `Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token`.

The incoming json details is like as shown below

**Manager incoming json**

```
{
  "name": "Rohit",
  "designation": "Manager",
  "item": {"name": "ABC", "desc": "1234"}
}
```

**Staff incoming json**

```
{
  "name": "Manu",
  "designation": "Staff",
  "item": "abc"
}
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a customer deserializer. If the node for the `"item"` field is an array, then deserialize it as an array, otherwise deserialize it as a String. For example

```
public static class EmployeeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Employee> {

    @Override
    public Employee deserialize(JsonParser jp,
            DeserializationContext dc)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        JsonNode root = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        emp.name = root.get("name").asText();
        emp.designation = root.get("designation").asText();
        JsonNode itemNode = root.get("item");
        if (itemNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode itemsNode = (ArrayNode) itemNode;
            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            for (JsonNode iNode : itemsNode) {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.name = iNode.get("name").asText();
                item.desc = iNode.get("desc").asText();
                items.add(item);
            }
            emp.items = items;
        } else if (itemNode.isObject()) {
            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            Item item = new Item();
            item.name = itemNode.get("name").asText();
            item.desc = itemNode.get("desc").asText();
            items.add(item);
            emp.items = items;
        } else {
            String item = root.get("item").asText();
            emp.item = item;
        }
        return emp;
    }
}
```

I actually added three cases for `"item"`. It could be a JSON array as multiple Items, a JSON object (which is what you have in your post) as a single Item, or a String for the staff. If it's a JSON object, I just create the single `Item` and added it to a `List`

Here is a complete test

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

public class EmployeeTest {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EmployeeDeserializer.class)
    public static class Employee {

        public String name;
        public String designation;
        public String item;
        public List<Item> items;
    }

    public static class Item {

        public String name;
        public String desc;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item{" + "name=" + name + ", desc=" + desc + '}';
        }
    }

    public static class EmployeeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Employee> {

        @Override
        public Employee deserialize(JsonParser jp,
                DeserializationContext dc)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            JsonNode root = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            emp.name = root.get("name").asText();
            emp.designation = root.get("designation").asText();
            JsonNode itemNode = root.get("item");
            if (itemNode.isArray()) {
                ArrayNode itemsNode = (ArrayNode) itemNode;
                List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
                for (JsonNode iNode : itemsNode) {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.name = iNode.get("name").asText();
                    item.desc = iNode.get("desc").asText();
                    items.add(item);
                }
                emp.items = items;
            } else if (itemNode.isObject()) {
                List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
                Item item = new Item();
                item.name = itemNode.get("name").asText();
                item.desc = itemNode.get("desc").asText();
                items.add(item);
                emp.items = items;
            } else {
                String item = root.get("item").asText();
                emp.item = item;
            }
            return emp;
        }
    }

    private static ObjectMapper mapper;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpMapper() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        //module.addDeserializer(Employee.class, new EmployeeDeserializer());
        //mapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_deserialize_manager_list_ok() throws Exception {
        final String mgrJson
                = "{\n"
                + "  \"name\": \"Rohit\",\n"
                + "  \"designation\": \"Manager\",\n"
                + "  \"item\": [{\"name\": \"ABC\", \"desc\": \"1234\"}]\n"
                + "}";
        Employee mgr = mapper.readValue(mgrJson, Employee.class);
        assertEquals("Rohit", mgr.name);
        assertEquals("Manager", mgr.designation);
        assertNull(mgr.item);
        assertEquals(1, mgr.items.size());
        assertEquals("ABC", mgr.items.get(0).name);
        assertEquals("1234", mgr.items.get(0).desc);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_deserialize_staff_string_ok() throws Exception {

        final String staffJson
                = "{\n"
                + "  \"name\": \"Manu\",\n"
                + "  \"designation\": \"Staff\",\n"
                + "  \"item\": \"abc\"\n"
                + "}";
        Employee staff = mapper.readValue(staffJson, Employee.class);
        assertEquals("Manu", staff.name);
        assertEquals("Staff", staff.designation);
        assertEquals("abc", staff.item);
        assertNull(staff.items);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_deserialize_single_item_ok() throws Exception {
        final String mgrJson
                = "{\n"
                + "  \"name\": \"Rohit\",\n"
                + "  \"designation\": \"Manager\",\n"
                + "  \"item\": {\"name\": \"ABC\", \"desc\": \"1234\"}\n"
                + "}";
        Employee mgr = mapper.readValue(mgrJson, Employee.class);
        assertEquals("Rohit", mgr.name);
        assertEquals("Manager", mgr.designation);
        assertNull(mgr.item);
        assertEquals(1, mgr.items.size());
        assertEquals("ABC", mgr.items.get(0).name);
        assertEquals("1234", mgr.items.get(0).desc);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine and working in Test, but say in junit you have registered the deserilizer in `@BeforeClass`. How we can register Deserilizer in dto for marshalling directly from REST service

Comment: You don't _have_ to register the deserializer with the `ObjectMapper`. You can just have `@JsonDeserialize(using = EmployeeDeserializer.class)` on top of the `Employee` class. It should work as well. Try it in the test. Just comment out everything in the `@BeforeClass` except the creation of the `ObjectMapper`

Comment: when I tried that I got `java.lang.NullPointerException at dto.test.EmployeeTest.should_deserialize_staff_string_ok(EmployeeTest.java:115)`

Comment: Not me. I tried it out myself. Did you accidentally comment out the creation of the `ObjectMapper`? I don't know what your line 115 is

Comment: can you update with yours , allso do we need to feine those classes as static

Comment: Updated. No I only make them static because they are inner classes. I did it so everything is all in one class to test. That won't be your case though in a real project.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Manager and Staff extend an abstract class Employee, and then use the 'designation' JSON property to distinguish them:

```
// note hashCode(), equals() and toString() methods left out for brevity!

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "designation")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(Staff.class), @JsonSubTypes.Type(Manager.class) })
public static abstract class Employee {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee() {
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("Manager")
public static final class Manager extends Employee {
    @JsonProperty("item")
    public List<Item> items;

    public Manager(String name, List<Item> items) {
        super(name);
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Manager() {
    }

    public static final class Item {
        public final String name;
        public final String desc;

        public Item(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("desc") String desc) {
            this.name = name;
            this.desc = desc;
        }
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("Staff")
public static final class Staff extends Employee {
    @JsonProperty("item")
    public String item;

    public Staff(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Staff() {
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
@Test
public void polymorphic_deserialization_of_manager() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES)
            .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
            .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED);
    String json = "{ name: 'Rohit', designation: 'Manager', item: { name: 'ABC', desc: '1234' } }";
    Employee employee = new Manager("Rohit", ImmutableList.of(new Manager.Item("ABC", "1234")));
    assertThat(mapper.readValue(json, Employee.class), equalTo(employee));
    assertThat(mapper.writeValueAsString(employee), equivalentTo(json));
}

@Test
public void polymorphic_deserialization_of_staff() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES).enable(
            JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES);
    String json = "{ name: 'Manu', designation: 'Staff', item: 'abc' }";
    Employee employee = new Staff("Manu", "abc");
    assertThat(mapper.readValue(json, Employee.class), equalTo(employee));
    assertThat(mapper.writeValueAsString(employee), equivalentTo(json));
}
```

Comment: but this works based on the designation value...i.e either Staff or Manager....but if the value differs then it wont work right...say if the  designation comes as Technician then it wont work