# Jackson ignore serialization of top-level field if all its nested fields are null

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize a POJO. I have nested fields in the POJO. Eg: serializing class `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass {
    private A a;
    private int i;
    //getters and setters
}

public class A {
    private String s;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I want that if String `s` is `null`, the entire property `A` does not get serialized. That is, if String `s` is `null`, I want the output to be:
`{"myClass":{"i":10}}`

But I am getting `{"myClass":{"A":{},"i":10}}` as the output instead.

I have set `NON_EMPTY` for serialization inclusion (`mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)`), but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate because it regards nested objects. The referred question does not handle it, and the solution there does not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot do this with standard annotations, but changing `MyClass.getA()` method in this way you should do the trick.

```
  public A getA() {
    if (a.getS() == null)
      return null;
    return a;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just to add  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyClass   implements Serializable {
    private A a;
    private int i;
    //getters and setters
}

public class A  implements Serializable{
    private String s;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: extends an `interface`?

Answer (score 0):

Generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the desired class.

```
public class A  extends Serializable{
    private String s;
    // getters and setters
    // hashCode() and equals()
}
```

Set an `Include.CUSTOM` in your parent class.

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = A.class)
public class MyClass extends Serializable {
    private A a;
    private int i;
    //getters and setters
}
```

All empty objects will be excluded and the output will be: `{"myClass":{"i":10}}`