# Same User dto but with different JsonProperty for two services

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am having two Spring Rest service **create-employee** and **create-staff** like as shown below

**create-employee**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create-employee", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createEmployee(final @RequestBody User user) {
    try {
        // employee createion logic
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error("Exception in createEmployee:"+exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

**create-staff**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create-staff", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createStaff(final @RequestBody User user) {
    try {
        // staff creation logic
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error("Exception in createStaff:"+exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

For both the services I am using a dto named `User` like as shown below:

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("employeeName")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    private Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("managerName")
    private String headName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getHeadName() {
        return headName;
    }

    public void setHeadName(String headName) {
        this.headName = headName;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that for both **create-employee** and **create-staff** since I am using **User.java** as the request body. The posting json body looks like this

```
{
 "employeeName" : "string",
 "age" : "integer",
 "managerName" : "string"
}
```

but actually what I want is that for **create-staff** service I would like to have the json body as below

```
{
 "staffName" : "string",
 "age" : "integer",
 "managerName" : "string"
}
```

and **create-staff** service I would like to have the json body as below

```
{
 "employeeName" : "string",
 "age" : "integer",
 "managerName" : "string"
}
```

But for both the services I need to use the same **User.java** dto but with different `JsonProperty` for the two services

Can anyone please hep me on this

Comment: What if you just used `name` and removed any need to do this?

Comment: @NickPredey You are right, but actually this was a client requirement and not only this many other services are there of similar scenarios . Like to know whether there is any way we can conditionally change the jsonproperty for staff and employee.

Comment: @AlexMan : you're trying to resolve an design problem by forcing the Json concept. Why don't have an member property `Statut statut` in the `User`. `enum Statut{ STAFF, USER, MANAGER, ....}`

Comment: @AlexMan you can add two property member in your user object and tell to Jackson to not return `null` value. `class User { String employeeName; String staffName; ... }`. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null

Answer (score 0):

Jackson also supports `JsonAlias` which might be helpful for you, just make sure  you updated your  jacskon mapper to version `2.9.1`

```
public class User {
    @JsonAlias({"employeeName","staffName"})
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    private Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("managerName")
    private String headName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getHeadName() {
        return headName;
    }

    public void setHeadName(String headName) {
        this.headName = headName;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right its request body and not response. with JsonView how we can do this conditionally

Comment: You have the sample in the documentation https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.java

Comment: using `JsonAlias` we can give multiple alias names for a property like  `@JsonAlias({ "staffName", "employeeName" })
  public String name;`. But how we can dynamically specify as `employeeName` property should come for **create-employee** service and `staffName` property should appear for **create-staff** service.