# How to pass different constructors as response in java

Tags: java

Response.java

```
public class Response{

private String mobileNo;
private String contractId;
private String sim;
private String imei;

public Response(String mobileNo, String contractId){
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    this.contractId = contractId;

}

public Response(String mobileNo, String contractId, String sim,
        String imei, String identificationType) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    this.contractId = contractId;
    this.sim = sim;
    this.imei = imei;
    this.identificationType = identificationType;
}



//Getter and Setter

}
```

MainEx.java

```
public class MainEx{

   Response  response = null;  

   public Response response(){

     String mobileNo = null;
     String contractId = null;
     String sim = null;
     String imei = null;

     if(something){
        response= new IVRAccountDetailsRs("777","4545"); 
     }
     else{
        response= new IVRAccountDetailsRs("777","4545","sim","imei");
     }
    return response;
   }
}
```

When if statement call return response as

```
{ "mobileNo" = "777";
  "contractId" = "4545";
  "sim"= null;
  "imei" = null;
}
```

But I want to get the response as bellow,

**When calling if statement**

Need to remove other two values.

```
{ "mobileNo" = "777";
  "contractId" = "4545";
}
```

If contractId and mobileNo null then output should be

```
{ "mobileNo" = null;
  "contractId" = null;
}
```

**When calling else statement**

```
{ "mobileNo" = "777";
  "contractId" = "4545";
  "sim"= "sim";
  "imei" = "imei";
}
```

if all values null

```
 { "mobileNo" = null;
      "contractId" = null;
      "sim"= null;
      "imei" =null;
    }
```

Used Jackson version is 2.4.1

What can I do about this?

Comment: You are using `gson`?

Comment: which libary you used to serialization

Comment: "But I want to get the response as bellow when calling if statement." => The real question is: **Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask it's not possible to manage just with serialization.

I suggest to edit Response class, removing the field that don't want send when they are null.

Then create another class that extends Response, that have the other 2 fields.

At this point you can instantiate which one you want based on your condition and return anyway as a Response object.

```
public class SimpleResponse {
    String mobileNo;
    String contractId;

    .....getters setters
}



public class FullResponse extends SimpleResponse {
    String sim;
    String imei;

    ....getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the version of SpringBoot is less than 1.3, it can only be handled programmatically

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Response {
    ///~
}
```

Spring boot can be configured directly from 1.3 in the `application.properties` file

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

[Official documentation for the jacksong configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

you can use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on sim and imei, Not on the whole class

```
public class Response{

private String mobileNo;
private String contractId;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String sim;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String imei;

public Response(String mobileNo, String contractId){
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    this.contractId = contractId;

}

public Response(String mobileNo, String contractId, String sim,
        String imei, String identificationType) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    this.contractId = contractId;
    this.sim = sim;
    this.imei = imei;
    this.identificationType = identificationType;
}
```

Comment: @Dev4World what r u using? `Gson` or `Jackson`

Comment: @Dev4World you can use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on `sim` and `imei`, Not on the whole class

Comment: When I use like this if some values null in the else statement those values remove from the response. But I need those null values with else statement response. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

For jackson serializers:

You can use annotation over your class, to [skip serializing null values](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields):

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Response{...}
```

Or add a parameter to your ObjectMapper configuration:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

This may be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null).

UPDATE:

You can also annotate  [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null).

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String sim;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String imei;
```

This way other properties will serialize null values, but those two will not be serialized with null value.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `jackson` then add this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) before field.

public class Response{

private String mobileNo;
private String contractId;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String sim;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String imei;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this annotation just above the getter of sim and imei

```
 @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

With Jackson > 1.9.11 and < 2.x use

```
  @JsonSerialize
```

annotation to do that:

```
   @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

For the version above 2:

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: Check again my answer

Comment: Maybe you have newer version of Jackson, put annotation above getter of filed that want ignore when is null

Comment: Jackson version is 2.4.1

Comment: Check this added answer part

Comment: I tried with your updated answer. Butt issue is same. I also updated my question.

Comment: I wrote another answer, cause the subject it's changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177070/discussion-between-frighi-and-dev4world).