# JAX-RS Response.ok(Object).build doesn't return empty field ("")

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have an object `myObject` with many values set to `null`, `first` set to `502296999` and the `second` is empty (`""`). In response I have:

```
"Phones": {
            "First": "502296999"
}
```

while I would like to receive this:

```
 "Phones": {
                "First": "502296999",
                "Second": ""

}
```

I am building the response this way:

```
return Response.ok(myObject).build();
```

Is there an easy way to also put the fields with value `""` into response? Or to force `Response.ok(myObject).build()` to always add those two fields no matter what is inside?

Comment: How is `myObject` populated?  For example, consturctor to set default values, or setters which check for null and convert to "".  But why do this?  It's more code to maintain and makes the consuming client do more work which would have to check for a non-empty value.  Also, consider a `List<Phone> phones` (easily extensible and consumable), compared to `First`, `Second`, etc.

Comment: `myObject` is created by constructor with values taken from body of REST-PUT method. I have noticed that the `build()` takes all not null and not empty parameters and I would like to change it to doesn't take just nulls.

Comment: It depends on the code of the class of myObject, on which JSON marshaller you're using, and on how you configured it. And we know nothing of all of that.

Comment: @JBNizet it's just a standard DAO class with `private String first;`
  and `private String second;` with getters, setters, overriden `hashCode()`, `equals()` and `toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, other function in mediator was checking if value is `empty` or `null` and didn't displaying it. By default `Response.ok(object).build()` return also the empty values:

```
"Phones": {
            "First": "502296999",
            "Second": ""
}
```

I have found that it can be configured by annotation `@JsonInclude`. Example here: [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)