# How to get Jackson to not output a field to XML when serializing

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null) I want to ignore a field in my java `POJO`. However, I want to always ignore the field whether or not it is null.

In my case I need to populate the field value for logic but later when I am outputting my xml I do not want this field included.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyNotification {
    @Setter @Getter private String id;
    @Setter @Getter private String time;
    @Setter @Getter private String flag;
    @Setter @Getter private String event;
    @Setter @Getter private String type;
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
    <MyNotification>
        <id>112314</id>
        <time>2019-08-20T08:41:45Z</time>
        <flag>new</flag>
        <type>T01</type>
    </MyNotification>
```

Have experimented with `@JsonIgnore` but when used the field does not get populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "event", allowSetters = true)
class MyNotification
```

From documentation for `allowSetters`:

> Property that can be enabled to allow "setters" to be used (that is,
>   prevent ignoral of setters for properties listed in value()).