# how to hide key in payload if value of that key is null using mapstruct in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

example dto generated:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "attributes": null
}
```

expecting response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test"
}
```

here I have to ignore attributes while returning. I cannot use **@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)** in dto because it has to be auto generated for other reasons and I cannot give @NotNull in model because it can be null for some cases. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` is something you can use

Comment: Hi. I don't understand how Mapstruct is related to your question. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm using mapstruct to map dto to model and model to dto. In mapstruct there is no option similar to @JsonInclude so I couldn't find how to ignore null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily add @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) to your Entity .

.`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) public class RealPerson implements Serializable {...`

Answer (score 0):

since attribute is a JSON field, including in the below part in map to json happens worked!

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
```

tried this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761975/11125169