# Optional fields in Java DTO with validation constraint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, dto

I've created a DTO with some properties with validation constraint (like all the properties must be present in JSON Object). Now, I want to make that DTO in a way like if a particular property is missing in JSON Object, it causes no error.

```
public class UserDTO{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNumber;
}
```

Now the JSON Object which I want to work could be like this (with missing email).

```
{
    name:"Hamza",
    address:"ABC",
    mobileNumber:"12345"
}
```

What should be done? Is there any annotation which makes the field optional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Answer (score 2):

you can add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) to ignore all unknow fields (if you don't know which need to ignore). or you can add @JsonIgnore on top of the field (if you know which field need to ignore during deserialization).

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserDTO {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNumber;
}
```