# Serialization of a read-only class ignoring nulls – without creating a custom ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

Suppose, I want Jackson to ignore nulls when serializing this particular object. I tried this (keep in mind, though, that the actual class being serialized is read-only)

```java
@RestController
public class SomeObjectController {
    @GetMapping("/some-object-with-no-nulls")
    @JsonInclude(content = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public Mono<SomeObject> getSomeObject() {
        return Mono.just(new SomeObject(null, "string"));
    }
    @NoArgsContructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class SomeObject {
        private String firstField;
        private String secondField;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work

```json
{
    firstField: null,
    secondField: "string"
}
```

The expected result is:

```json
{
    secondField: "string"
}
```

I get what I want if I register a custom `ObjectMapper`. But I may not necessarily want that behavior for all my endpoints (even if they serve `SomeObject` too)

```java
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

I also would like to avoid writing a custom serializator. It may be possible, but I prefer declarative solutions (while realizing their drawbacks)

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Comment: @Chaosfire nope. See the edit please

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean with readonly. Do you mean class coming from a library, when you don't have access to the source code?

Comment: @Chaosfire exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner solution is to to write custom serializer for `SomeObject` and register it with the existing instance of `ObjectMapper`.

Since you don't want to do that, if `SomeObject` is extensible (non final), you can use inheritance and add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on *your* class.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SomeObjectInheritor extends SomeObject {

  public static SomeObjectInheritor fromParent(SomeObject someObject) {
    SomeObjectInheritor inheritor = new SomeObjectInheritor();
    inheritor.setFirstField(someObject.getFirstField());
    inheritor.setSecondField(someObject.getSecondField());
    return inheritor;
  }
}
```

You can replace `SomeObject` instances with `SomeObjectInheritor`, or you can use it only for the actual serialization.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //use SomeObjectInheritor instead of SomeObject
    SomeObject someObject = new SomeObjectInheritor();
    someObject.setSecondField("val");
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject));

    //use SomeObjectInheritor only for the actual serialization
    SomeObject anotherObj = new SomeObject();
    anotherObj.setSecondField("second value");
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(SomeObjectInheritor.fromParent(anotherObj)));
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
{"secondField":"val"}
```

for `someObject` and

```
{"secondField":"second value"}
```

for `anotherObj` respectively. In both cases the null property is not serialized.

If `SomeObject` is `final`, I am afraid, that your only option is writing a serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add json include on top of class SomeObject

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to tell that the actual class is read-only