# Jackson serialization: change default inclusion on a per serialization invocation basis

Tags: jackson

I have an ObjectMapper that currently includes explicit nulls when it serializes objects. I want to experiment with `Include.NON_NULL`. However, I don't want to do this via class or property annotations as is the [commonly recommended solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null). I also don't want to change the global default on my mapper, or create a second mapper. Instead, I want to decide on a per serialization method invocation basis whether or not the default inclusion is Include.NON_NULL or not.

Poking around the code and java docs, it seems like the variants of `mapper.writer()` are close to what I'm looking for in that they allow you to efficiently set some per-serialization configs. But I can't quite find what I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this with `mapper.writer()` or some other means that allows me to make the inclusion decision dynamically while still leveraging the mapper cache for efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Got confirmation from the project lead that this is not possible due to how caching is implemented - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/4372#issuecomment-1933445335